# JQuery Ajax Asynchronous Redirection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, fosjsroutingbundle

I face a weird issue while redirecting after an *asynchronous* ajax POST request. I want to send an asynchronous POST request (file upload) to the server and until I wait for it to finish, since it takes some time, I want to redirect to a different route and there I can watch the status of the upload. My problem is that even if I state that the request is **async** it first waits for this request to finish, *synchronously* and then redirects me. 
Am I missing anything by chance?

```
upload.save = function (data) {
    var self = this,
        result = self.uploadType.getSummaryData();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Routing.generate('save'),
        data: JSON.stringify({
            //My data
        }),
        cache: false,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: self
    });

    // Redirection
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace(Routing.generate('log'));
    }, 3000);
};
```

I am using Symfony 3.4 and JQuery version is 2.1 and for the redirect I use the FOS JS Routing Bundle v~1.4

Comment: That's not possible, if your page redirects, then your upload will be canceled, unless you are doing client side routing.

Comment: @IwanWijaya Yep, the redirection is client side. My question is, isn't it possible to just redirect to this route, while the upload goes on? why does it wait for the 'save' route to finish?

Comment: Simple answer is you can't replace the window the request is being made in without aborting the request. Client side routing is completely different ...think *"single page app"*.

Comment: You could accept the data and let background process run on server processing the data update sesssion with progreess details. Then initial request would be done very quickly and you can poll another script for progress updates

Comment: Ok, so in any case the *save* POST request should be finished on the client side for the redirection to happen, just on the same time I can create a process on the server that the client doesn't care about

Comment: The thing is that weirdly, this is working on an older branch so I can see the redirection even if the previous *save* request is not finished and on the new page the process runs on the server side until it completes, but after updating some composer dependencies (like Guzzle from 5->6) and didn't touch anything on the code the redirection doesn't work on master which puzzles me

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to be on the server side. It seems like PHP needs to end the current session and store the session data with **session_write_close()** so that each ajax request doesn't have to wait for the next one if *async* is **true**.

So this is needed to allow concurrent request from the client side

Answer (score -1):

When async setting is set to false, a Synchronous call is made instead of an Asynchronous call.

```
 $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Routing.generate('save'),
        data: JSON.stringify({
            //My data
        }),
        cache: false,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: self,
        async: false
    });
```

When async setting is set to true, a Asynchronous call is made instead of an Synchronous call.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that from the documentation. In my case I am looking for an async approach, so even *save* is not finished, do a client redirection to *log*

Comment: `async: false` is a horrible practice and should never ever be used. It is also deprecated by browser vendors and displays console warnings when you do try to use it. Don't do this!